# Relación de productos con multiples precios y tamaños

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Me encuentro diseñando una base de datos para un sistema de registro de pedidos para una pizzería. Tengo una tabla llamada "productos" que contiene estos atributos:

```
| PRODUCTOS             |
| --------------------- |
| id          | int     |
| nombre      | varchar |
| descripción | varchar |
| url_imagen  | varchar |
| precio      | decimal |
| tamaño      | varchar |
| publicado   | boolean |
```

Al ingresar registros en dicha tabla se generaba una redundancia en los datos, por lo que decidí separarlos en 3 tablas: Precios, Tamaños y Productos que se relacionan de la siguiente manera:

```
| PRODUCTOS             |
| --------------------- |
| id          | int     |
| nombre      | varchar |
| descripción | varchar |
| url_imagen  | varchar |
| publicado   | boolean |

| TAMAÑOS          |
| ---------------- |
| id     | int     |
| tamaño | varchar |

| PRECIOS         |
| --------------- |
| id    | int     |
| valor | decimal |
```

1 producto puede tener diferentes tamaños y 1 mismo tamaño puede estar presente en uno o varios productos, de igual manera 1 producto puede tener diferentes precios en relación a su tamaño y sabor y 1 mismo precio suele repetirse para muchos productos, igualmente no todos los productos tienen un tamaño y solo tienen un precio único.

Ejemplo:

Un producto en este caso 1 pizza de jamón tiene estos tamaños: tamaño personal, tamaño mediano y tamaño familiar, su precio varía de acuerdo a su tamaño y de acuerdo a su sabor de esta manera:

- 1 pizza de jamón personal cuesta 7 euros.
- 1 pizza de jamón mediana cuesta 10 euros.
- 1 pizza de jamón familiar cuesta 15 euros.

Mientras que una pizza hawaiana solo tiene disponible el tamaño mediano y grande y su precio cambia solo en la pizza grande:

- 1 pizza hawaiana mediana cuesta 10 euros.
- 1 pizza hawaiana grande cuesta 20 euros.

Aquí otros ejemplos de diferentes productos:

- Coca-Cola 1.5L cuesta 2 euros.
- Coca-Cola 2L cuesta 2,5 euros.
- Pepsi 2L cuesta 2 euros.
- Lasaña cuesta 5 euros (No tiene tamaño y solo tiene un precio único).

Lo primero que hice fue relacionar mi tabla de productos y tamaños con una relación de muchos a muchos, hasta ahí todo correcto.

```
| PRODUCTO_TAMAÑO    |
| ------------------ |
| id           | int |
| producto_id  | int |
| tamaño_id    | int |
```

Pero para la tabla de precios no encuentro la forma de relacionarla, lo que probé fue agregar una relación de precios con la tabla pivote de productos y tamaños. Pero como en muchos productos el precio suele ser el mismo, esto acaba generando una redundancia en los precios.

```
| PRODUCTO_TAMAÑO       |
| --------------------- |
| id          | int     |
| producto_id | int     |
| tamaño_id   | int     |
| precio      | decimal |
```

¿Cómo puedo relacionar estas 3 tablas de la manera más óptima?

Comment: Yo consideraría la pizza grande como un producto y la pizza pequeña como otro producto y no como el mismo producto con distintos tamaño, esto haría más fácil todo.
Si no es lo que buscas, plantéate utilizar una tabla con una clave compuesta por tamaño, producto y precio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Técnicamente podrías hacerlo igual que con la otra tabla. Podrías crear una tabla pivote `PRODUCTO_PRECIO` con las columnas (id, producto_id, precio_id)

De todas formas *no* lo haría así. Especialmente para la tabla de precios. No tiene sentido tener los precios en otra tabla para que sean reutilizados por otros productos porque el precio es un dato muy variable. Quizás en una pizzería no tanto, pero es poco común repetir precios.

Además, imagina que dos productos comparten un precio y quieres cambiar el precio de sólo uno de ellos.

Con esa estructura lo que tendrías que hacer es eliminar el registro de PRODUCTO_PRECIO, ver si ya tienes el precio definido en la tabla de precios, si no lo tienes definido definirlo, y finalmente crear un registro en la tabla producto_precio que relacione tu producto y el nuevo precio.

O simplemente piensa que aunque ahora los precios son: 2,5, 2 y 5 (que se suelen repetir), los requerimientos de tu cliente pueden cambiar y empezar a tener precios más 'aleatorios' y menos repetidos.

No tiene sentido intentar normalizar la columna de precios. Simplemente déjala en la tabla de productos como inicialmente tenías.

El caso de los tamaños es un poco diferente. Puedes normalizarlo en otra tabla si quieres, pero para este caso concreto tienes algo mejor: [los tipos enumerados](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) (en otras bases de datos se podría hacer lo mismo con check constraints)

Con los tipos enumerados garantizas que no se pueda insertar/actualizar esa columna con un valor que no sea uno de los valores permitidos de la lista.

Únicamente tendría sentido sacar el tamaño en otra tabla si quisieras guardar propiedades del tamaño. Por ejemplo:

(id_tamaño, nombre, descripción, altura_minima, anchura_minima, profundidad_minima, ...)

Si necesitas algo así, tendrás que sacarlo a una tabla. Si lo único que necesitas es garantizar que la columna de tamaño siempre acepta una serie de valores válidos, el tipo enumerado es tu mejor opción.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta!! La verdad no habia pensando que al plantear los precios como entidad, al modificar un precio este cambiaria para todos los productos relacionados con dicho precio, soy algo novato en este tema por lo que al existir redundancia lo que intentaba era separar todo en tablas independientes, muchas gracias por su ayuda.